Django error - ['“” value must be a decimal number.']
I'm trying to add a new price field into Django models. Here is my code I've added into models.py :
price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00, null=True
    )

when I try to migrate I'm having this error:
.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1807, in to_python        
    raise exceptions.ValidationError(
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“” value must be a decimal number.']

Tried to add :
blank=True

Didn't work.

Can you share the corresponding migration file?

from django.db import migrations, models
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
dependencies = [
    ("codered", "0021_alter_coffeevariety_price"),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name="coffeevariety",
        name="price",
        field=models.DecimalField(
            decimal_places=2, default=0.0, max_digits=10, null=True
        ),
    ),
]


Please show the full traceback to your error, not just the couple last lines.

Applying codered.0003_coffeevariety_price...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "G:\Django-ch.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields_init_.py", line 1805, in to_python
decimal_value = decimal.Decimal(value)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]
